# Rebuild a Centos kernel from a Debian netboot

Tags: centos, kernel, bootable

I have (had) a Centos 7 system running on a server at OVH, booting from hard disk. I did a kernel update, and being in too much of a hurry rebooted just after it looked like all went well.

It didn't. Not only was the old kernel removed, there is no initramfs for the current kernel (4.9.185-xxxx-std-ipv6-64). On boot, grub looks for the old, nonexistent kernel (there is an initramfs 4.9.184 but no kernel) and the system won't boot.

Grub does see the filesystems, including the root (md/md2)

The system is running a raid array under LVM. I have tried booting in with a OVH recovery kernel, mounting the drive, chrooting in and building a new initramfs with

```
dracut --mdadmconf --lvmconf --kver 4.9.185-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
```

I then boot, get into grub and execute these commands:

```
set root=(md/md2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.185-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 root=/dev/md2
initrd /boot/initramfs-4.9.185-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
boot
```

I've also tried using the volume's UUID for the root argument (root=UUID=...)

In both cases, the boot process gets to a minimal system but can't find dev/md2 and dracut just waits forever.

I have made the system usable again by switching to the OVH netboot option, which gets me

Linux {servername} 4.9.182-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #768030 SMP Tue Jun 18 08:30:59 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Is there now any way I can build an initramfs for the 4.9.185 kernel, or basically anything else that will get me back to the point where I can boot from disk?

At this point I have just over 1TB of backups on this machine under a dozen different accounts, so if I can't rebuild in place, it will be a significant PITA. I'll have to offload the data, rebuild, and bring the data back... and then write a moron script that won't let me reboot on a busted environment.

Comment: Those aren't CentOS kernels, so you'll have to talk to your hosting provider to find out what's going on with their kernels.

Comment: Pretty close to my first guess. Asking OVH for kernel support is just going to get me a "start over" response, so I guess that's where It's at. Thanks.